# How to create a file Object out of an image file in Phonegap javascript...?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have a image `(relative URL="/images/image.jpg")` , how to get a file object of this image using this URL in JavaScript or Phonegap api ....

```
<img src="/images/image1.jpg" />
```

the above is the image displayed, i need to get the file object of this image .

Any help is greatly appreciated ...

Comment: Is this image packaged as part of your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to get a file object of that image as it is not part of the file system. Instead it is a packaged part of your application.